# Supporting custom hooks in existing cpp class

Tags: c++

I am designing support for custom hooks in existing C++ class.

```
class NotMyClass {
  public: 
    void DoSomething() {
      // Needs custom logic here.
      hook_.DoSomethingCustom();
    }

  protected:
    Hook hook_;
    int not_my_class_inner_variable_1_;
    Node not_my_class_inner_variable_2_;
    ...... More Class vars.....
}

class Hook {
  public: 
    void DoSomethingCustom() {
    // Some custom logic that needs to access not_my_class_inner_variable_1_, not_my_class_inner_variable_2 etc. .
    }
}
```

**Adding some more context here after initial comments:** `NotMyClass` class is autogenerated and no custom logic can be added to this class. We want to be able to add custom hooks inside the autogenerated classes. So the plan was to instead pass/ingect in a `Hook` class that will be able to provide some custom processing. The autogenerated `NotMyClass` class will have `hook_. DoSomethingCustom()`.

What's the best way to access `NotMyClass`  member variables inside `Hook` ?

I don't want to change the class structure(that is use inheritence) of `NotMyClass` due to additional constraints.

Is making `Hook` a friend of `NotMyClass` a good option and then passing `NotMyClass` as `this` to `Hook` functions ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the hook to be selectable at runtime or at compile-time?

Comment: Its at compile time, we know what hook to run at compile time.

Comment: Then, maybe replace `private` with `protected` and "hook" by inheriting? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Unfortunately inheriting is not an option here. The classes are final and due to the current structure we cannot change the inheritence structure of existing MyClass class.

Comment: Do the member variables need to stay `private`?

Comment: Basically, you *can't* do what you ask in the title due to violation of Open-Closed-Principle. That means, you will change the existing class's behavior if you expose its private members as (mutable) variables to the new `Hook` class. I would say - design a new class and don't look back on existing private members.

Comment: Details and clarity. Don't have us drag the specifics out please.

Comment: What's the reason for `final` and why you can't drop it?

Comment: _"I don't want to change the class structure of MyClass due to additional constraints."_ - Are those self imposed due to time constraints (or something else irrelevant to the problem at hand)?

Comment: If you absolutely must avoid changing `MyClass` (i.e., it's better named as `NotMyClass`),  you could pass its fields to the method explicitly by reference to be modified.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the class, so cannot change the structure. I am only allowed to add hooks to existing code.

Comment: Why are you considering making the hook a `friend`, if you can't modify the class? Also, I start to think that I don't understand what "hook" means for you. Normally it's something that intercepts a function call and changes the behavior.

Comment: "Normally it's something that intercepts a function call and changes the behavior": Yeah thats the exact definition for me. My thoughts behind making `Hook` a friend of `NotMyClass`  was so that I can use its member variables. Probably a stupid design, just wanted to have feedback :)

Comment: What I'm saying is that adding a friend requires modifying `NotMyClass`, and so is removing `final`. Is there only one hook, or there should be room for more than one? Also please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: Unrelated: I voted to close this because I find the question lacking details and clarity. Yet - it attracts a lot of attention and good discussion. I just wish the actual question was updated to motivate that it stays open.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see what you mean now. My main motivation behind considering using `friend` was to be able to pass `this` in the Hooks member functions so that I dont have to pass each of the member of `NotMyClass` variables individually.

Comment: So the answer is yes, there's only one hook. If so, why a separate class is needed at all? Why not implemented all the logic directly in the `NotMyClass`? I don't buy "can't modify it", since you can, if you consider adding a `friend`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is no spoon. There are turtles - all the way down.

Comment: After your most recent clarification, I believe the "Friend class" approach seems reasonable for your use-case. In that case, the friend declaration can always be part of the auto-generated code and you can modify your Hook as required. On the other hand, template metaprogramming in modern C++ gives you a LOT of flexibility, which can replace most instances of automatic code generation and is far superior for maintainability. Maybe your application warrants automatic code generation but keep in mind that a lot of aplications actually do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem cannot be solved as stated, i.e., without breaking the [Open-Closed-Principle (OCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), which says that "classes (and other things) should be open for extension but closed for modification." In this case, this means that you shouldn't try to both (a) leave `MyClass` unchanged and (b) access its private or protected members from outside. Private (or protected) signal things that are not accessed from the outside, that's literally what `private` (or `protected`) are designed for. You can circumvent this ([old ways](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm), [new ways](https://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)) but you shouldn't.

The answer by sanitizedUser modifies `MyClass`, which is undesirable as per the question. A hacky but straight-forward suggestion to your problem might be to pass the fields to be modified explicitly to the method by reference:

```
class MyClass {
  public: 
    void DoSomething() {
      // Pass references to the fields you want to modify.
      hook_.DoSomethingCustom(my_class_inner_variable_1_, my_class_inner_variable_2_);
    }

  protected:
    Hook hook_;
    int my_class_inner_variable_1_;
    Node my_class_inner_variable_2_;
}

class Hook {
  public: 
    void DoSomethingCustom(int &inner_variable_1, Node& inner_variable_2_) {
      // Use the data members.
    }
}
```

To signal that your `Hook` class explicitly is allowed to access members of `MyClass`, you could declare it as a [friend](https://%20https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend). Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {};

class MyClass;

class Hook {
  public: 
    void DoSomethingCustom(MyClass &m);
};

class MyClass {
    friend Hook;  // Allows the Hook class to access our members!

  public: 
    MyClass(Hook h): hook_(h) {}

    void DoSomething() {
      // Pass references to the fields you want to modify.
      hook_.DoSomethingCustom(*this);
    }

    void print_my_class_inner_variable_1_() {
        std::cout << my_class_inner_variable_1_ << std::endl; 
    }

  protected:
    Hook hook_;
    int my_class_inner_variable_1_;
    Node my_class_inner_variable_2_;
};

void Hook::DoSomethingCustom(MyClass &m) {
      // Allowed to access private member because we are a friend!
      m.my_class_inner_variable_1_ = 42;
}

int main() {
    MyClass c{Hook{}};
    c.print_my_class_inner_variable_1_();
    c.DoSomething();
    c.print_my_class_inner_variable_1_();
}
```

*Note: your whole design with this "Hook" looks very weird to me. How do you "add hooks" to this thing (which imho is one of the defining requirements for calling something a "[hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)")? I'm sure if you posted a lot more context, people here would suggest a very different larger-scale design.*

Comment: Is making `Hook` a friend of `NotMyClass` a good option and then passing `NotMyClass` as `this` to `Hook` functions ?

Comment: and still I would mention in the answer that you one should avoid breaking the OCP. The new `Hook` class now is allowed to unpredictably modify "inner variables" which would change or break the specifications of the existing `MyClass` class

Comment: @danishsodhi this design does not have *good* options. You will have a lot of troubles with any of that approaches because you violate OCP

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Any suggestion how to phrase "mention in the answer that you opne should avoid breaking the OCP"? The only advice I can derive from OCP in this case is "the problem cannot be solved".

Comment: *"the problem cannot be solved*" - the best first line of the answer) And then "if you want to suffer for the next 10 years, you can..." ;)

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka I upvoted after the latest edit and should probably be good with that, but I find that a rhetorical question in an answer doesn't really work for a Q&A. Specifically: _"How do you...?"_ in your end note.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it may be that the question is not appropriate (although I don't fully understand why you think that). However, it certainly was not rhetorical. I was wondering what actual design problem OP might be having and doubted this kind of construct can be called a "hook", or be very useful for that matter.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka You may disregard my reasoning for the question not being clear as frustration on my part. I'm used and rely on clear questions. As for your own remarks - great! Put those in the answer. I've already upvoted but it'll do the answer good (in my book).

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Sorry I added some more context, hope it will help clarify my thoughts :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an ideal solution but if you are allowed to declare the `Hook` class a friend of `NotMyClass` then the following code somewhat works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class NotMyClass;

class Hook {
  public: 
    void DoSomethingCustom(const NotMyClass& c);
};

class NotMyClass {
  friend Hook;
  
  public:
    void DoSomething() {
      hook_.DoSomethingCustom(*this);
    }

  protected:
    Hook hook_;
    int not_my_class_inner_variable_1_;
    // Commenting Node member out because the definition of it is missing.
    // Node not_my_class_inner_variable_2_;
};

void Hook::DoSomethingCustom(const NotMyClass& c) {
    std::cout << c.not_my_class_inner_variable_1_ << '\n';
}

int main() {
    NotMyClass{}.DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Output.

```
0
```

If you can modify `NotMyClass` entirely then I advice you to use polymorphism and declare `Hook` as an abstract class. This way its behaviour can be swapped more easily.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class State>
struct Hook {
    virtual State run(const State& s) const = 0;
};

struct ExampleState {
    int number;
    std::string text;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const ExampleState& state) {
    stream << state.number << ", " << state.text << '\n';
    return stream;
}

struct ExampleHook : public Hook<ExampleState> {
    ExampleState run(const ExampleState& s) const override;
};

class Receiver {
    public:
        void DoSomething();
        Receiver(const Hook<ExampleState>* const hook);
    
    private:
        const Hook<ExampleState>* const hook;
        ExampleState state;
};

ExampleState ExampleHook::run(const ExampleState& s) const {
    // Returning a modified state.
    return {
        s.number + 1,
        "Modified " + s.text
    };
}

void Receiver::DoSomething() {
    std::cout << "Original state:\n" << this->state;
    this->state = this->hook->run(this->state);
    std::cout << "Modified state:\n" << this->state;
}

Receiver::Receiver(const Hook<ExampleState>* const hook)
    : hook(hook), state{0, "hello"} {}

int main() {
    ExampleHook hook;
    Receiver receiver(&hook);
    receiver.DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Output.

```
Original state:
0, hello
Modified state:
1, Modified hello
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any downsides of declaring `Hook` as friend ? Can you elaborate why isn't this a good solution ?

Comment: @danishsodhi Yes, there are downsides. As others have noted, you would break the Open-Closed Principle which then allows any other developer to modify the state of `NotMyClass` without your knowledge. This can lead to hard-to-track bugs appearing. In this situation, you should consider changing the design. I added one such idea at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is declaring data members of class `MyClass` public and then passing a reference to an instance of `MyClass` to an instance of `Hook`.

```cpp
class MyClass {
  public: 
    void DoSomething() {
      // Pass a reference to this.
      hook_.DoSomethingCustom(*this);
    }

  public:
    Hook hook_;
    int my_class_inner_variable_1_;
    Node my_class_inner_variable_2_;
}

class Hook {
  public: 
    void DoSomethingCustom(const MyClass& c) {
      // Use the data members.
      auto& ref1 = c.my_class_inner_variable_1_;
      auto& ref2 = c.my_class_inner_variable_2_;
    }
}
```

If you cannot declare the members `public` because this is a legacy code, then there is always the evil option.

```cpp
#define protected public

// Your code.

#undef protected
```

However, if this code is already compiled as a dynamic library then you are out of luck.

Comment: `#define protected public` - no ... just **no**

Comment: @TedLyngmo You can undefine it later.

Comment: declaring mutable member variables public is the same as making them global...

Comment: this answer would be less harmful if it suggested to define `Hook` as a `friend`. There are no options otherwise (it doesn't mean one should do it)

Comment: @sanitizedUser _"You can undefine it later"_ - I get that your suggestion was half serious but, it breaks/violates existing code (if it compiles - many compilers will refuse it). NO! - Re`define`ing keywords is never the solution!

Comment: There are better ways to access private members (something based on [this](https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/1528856)).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, not that one either I would say. It doesn't seem to supply the user with defined behavioral access to private members. I'd start with `boost`s magic get. If it doesn't compile, one has no reason tampering with the members.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My brain refuses to parse your comment. :) What's "defined behavioral access"?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat :-D It's what happens after forced entry. Noone knows.

Comment: @TedLyngmo However, this can be solved with in-house tools that monitor access to members whose access modifier has been overwritten. Just a simple check during compiling would suffice.

Comment: @sanitizedUser _"Just a simple check during compiling would suffice"_ - Anyone here could bypass such a check in about 1000 keystrokes so I wouldn't rely on such tools.

Comment: And how is that possible? Those tools stop the compilation process if such an access is detected. They are the last thing in the pipeline.

Comment: @sanitizedUser If you ask me(?) I'd make a `trait` to cast whatever I see into whatever I want. I'll use CRTP to hide specifics if needed. (ok, that's about 1000 keystrokes). Note: It'll still be _undefined behavior_ as your keyword metamorphism - as it should.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok. I guess if one tries it is possible.

Comment: @sanitizedUser Precisely, and `#define protected public` has already defined everything that compiles the code to have undefined behavior, so, why not?